# How to pull out JSON blobs from large random string which contains plain text and JSON

Tags: python, json, filter

I have a large file full of short JSON blobs, and random strings between the JSON.

The JSON objects are all different and do not contain a regular format. The strings also contain random data and do not have a consistent length or structure.

How would I filter this string to only pull out the valid JSON?

Does Python have a string filter function which could be used to reject anything is not JSON?
Every sample I can find will either examine the entire string to understand if it's JSON, which we know will not work for this example.

Comment: Why would Python have a string filter function *for that*?

Comment: How would it know which substring to pull out? For example, `print(a = 3)` is an invalid python syntax; should `print()` or `a = 3` be pulled out?

Answer (score 0):

There's a slow, tedious approach you can take. You can attempt to parse it, and each time you get an exception, that gives you information about what to discard. You either discard a prefix that couldn't be parsed as JSON, or you attempt to reparse a prefix followed by additional data, then parsing whatever comes after the successful parse.

```
import json

def extract_json_values(input_str):
    results = []
    while input_str:
        try:
            value = json.loads(input_str)
            input_str = ""
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as exc:
            if str(exc).startswith("Expecting value"):   
                input_str = input_str[exc.pos+1:]
                continue
            elif str(exc).startswith("Extra data"):
                value = json.loads(input_str[:exc.pos])
                input_str = input_str[exc.pos:]
        results.append(value)
    return results

for x in extract_json_values('x"foo"x3[1,2,3]asfa{"bar": "baz"}'):
    print(x)
```

This should output

```
foo
3
[1, 2, 3]
{'bar': 'baz'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a greedy approach to scan through all substrings of the file content for valid JSON blobs, yielding on the longest match:

```
import json

def extract_json_blobs(content):
    i = 0
    while i < len(content):
        if content[i] == '{':
            for j in range(len(content) - 1, i, -1):
                if content[j] == '}':
                    try:
                        yield json.loads(content[i:j+1])
                        i = j
                        break
                    except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
                        pass
        i += 1

>>> content = 'abd 123 ** 9 {. {"id":"10"} aaasd {"foo": {"id": [1234]}} aae 324'
>>> for blob in extract_json_blobs(content):
>>>    print(blob)
{'id': '10'}
{'foo': {'id': [1234]}}
```

If you want to yield *any* valid JSON (i.e., not only JSON "objects") drop the checks on `{` and `}` above.